# Simultaneous differential equations with conditional change of a coefficient

Tags: matlab, conditional-statements, modeling, differential-equations

I want to model a Chemostat (a certain kind of bioreactor).
I setup the following system which can be solved with the ode45 method:

```
%chemostat model, based on:
%DCc=-v0*Cc/V + umax*Cs*Cc/(Ks+Cs)-rd -->Change of cell concentration over time
%Dcs=(v0/V)*(Cs0-Cs) - Cc*(Ys*umax*Cs/(Ks+Cs)-m) -->Change of substrate concentration over time

function dydt=sys(t,y,v0,V,umax,Ks,rd,Cs0,Ys,m)
         dydt=[-(v0/V)*y(1)+(umax*y(1)*y(2))/(Ks+y(2))-rd; 
               (v0/V)*(Cs0-y(2))-(Ys*umax*y(2)*y(1))/(Ks+y(2))];
```

I call the function with:

```
[t,y]=ode45(@systemEquations, [0 40],[1 100],[],**v0**, V,umax,Ks,rd,Cs0,Ys,m);
```

**The values of all the additional coefficients are set before running the calculation. So far everything works.
Now I would like v0 to be dependent on the system state. E.g. initially v0 = 0 and when my cell concentration surpasses a certain value I want it to change.**

The problem is, I absolutely have no idea how to implement this. The Matlab help of the ode solver wasn't of any help either...

Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Cheers,
dahlai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your Differential System function to take care of it for you! First formulate a v0 as a function of time and state:

```
function v0 = funV0( t, y )
    v0 = 1;
    if y(1) > 5
        v0 = y(2); % As an example, if [Y1] > 5, then set v0 = [Y2]
    end
end
```

Then utilize that function in your differential system. You can either pass @funV0 as a parameter, or let your differential system function execute it directly. I will treat it as a parameter for now.

```
function dydt=sys(t,y,v0,V,umax,Ks,rd,Cs0,Ys,m)
     dydt=[-(v0(t,y)/V)*y(1)+(umax*y(1)*y(2))/(Ks+y(2))-rd; 
           (v0(t,y)/V)*(Cs0-y(2))-(Ys*umax*y(2)*y(1))/(Ks+y(2))];
```

Called using:

```
[t,y]=ode45(@systemEquations, [0 40],[1 100],[],@funV0, V,umax,Ks,rd,Cs0,Ys,m);
```

Of course, this principle can be applied to any time or state dependent parameter. This style also allows you to try various parameter functions Let's say you are approximating the parameter as a function of state: You can trial out different approximations by passing in different V0 functions.

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Thank you Rollen! This is exactly what I was looking for. I tried to implement it this way, but didn't know that I would have to exchange v0 with v0(t,y).

Comment: At first I thought this did not work, but I just miscopied part of the code.